# Intel server hardware failure; does not work

Tags: intel, hardware

I have a rackmount server from INTEL that suddenly stopped working. The model is SR2400SYSD2. The server was functional and was shut down normaly for relocation. After being connected again it refuses to function at all. Both VGA ports (back and front) send no signal to any connected monitor. The LEDs on the keyboard do not shine. The thing is that when the power switch is pressed the server power-cycles normaly. I have openned the chassis and everything is in place. Please help.

Comment: Why not contact intel? There are likely way too many possible causes for this to be answerable.

Comment: The machine is ancient, on top. Nonoe should run that in production. We have 1 machine of similar same age in a data center that is currently on life support (gets replaced with next upgrade).

Comment: @TomTom, sometimes you get stuck with the dregs :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reseating the various cards in the system to make sure everything has good contact? I especially look at checking the RAM, this is usually what gets a little loose and needs to be reseated in order for the system to actually POST.

It sounds like the power to the system is fine, but it's not posting.  So check the RAM, maybe the CPU sockets and see if that helps.

Comment: I checked the RAM and it turns out that half the slots (three out of six) have "gone bad". I appreciate the understanding.

Answer (score 11):

> Please help

Dude, a reality check. Machines BREAK DOWN. When they break down, they get fixed or replaces. YOu must be VERY new to life if you never needed for example a car mechanic. Things DO break down, there is nothing special about it.

Now, what to do? SIMPLE.

Depending on when the server was purchased, do one of the following:

- contact shop for repair if under shop warranty.
- contact intel for repair if under intel warranty
- ask someone with a clue to have a short look. It COULD Just be a replacement power supply.
- throw away and get new machine.

In general, this is a site for professional admins. I would expect a professional admin to be able to make a short diagnosis of the most obvious issues. Then refer that to a technician.

Sorry, we can not magically fix broken hardware over the internet. I suggest you get a basic education into how buying things work - the warranty part may be of particular interest. Depends how old the server is.

Looking at the model number in google reveals it is likely QUITE old - I see "Controller Type: Ultra320 SCSI" and that is by no means something I would expect in any machine of the last years. I also seem to be able to get some of them for a joke of a price, so - looks like the best is the garbage route and get a decent modern system.

Comment: I highly doubt his system is still under warranty as it's so old.

Comment: I agree. VERY unlikely, but some stuff gets like 5+ years.

Comment: Yep, Dell does up to 3-years initial and up to 3 years after that at most.

Comment: Which is 6. I am just not sure HOW old that server es. Not only in particular - I am not SO familiar with Intel (mostly used AMD the last years) so I simply have no idea about that processor there ;)

Comment: Your phone will outperform it these days...